# syntax error in calculation of attendance % in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT name, DISTINCT studentid, count(attendance) 
 from attendance a,students s 
 where attendance = 'p'and s.studentid=a.studentid  
having count(attendance)<3/4*sum(attendance);
```

I have 2 tables attendance and students from which i wanna choose the name of the student(from student table) and attendance (from attendance table) where studentid is the foreign key of those students whose attendance<75%. i save attendance as p and a for present and absent respectively.

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

**Data prep**

```
create table attendance (studentid int, attendance char(1));

insert into attendance values (1,'p'),(1,'a'),(2,'p'),(2,'p'),(2,'a'),(3,'p');
```

**Data**

```
select * from students;
+-----------+------+
| studentid | name |
+-----------+------+
|         1 | John |
|         2 | Matt |
|         3 | Mary |
+-----------+------+

select * from attendance;
+-----------+------------+
| studentid | attendance |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 | p          |
|         1 | a          |
|         2 | p          |
|         2 | p          |
|         2 | a          |
|         3 | p          |
+-----------+------------+
```

**Query**

```
select s.*, a.total, a.p_present
from students s
inner join (
    select studentid, count(*) as total, sum(case attendance when 'p' then 1 else 0 end) * 100/count(*) as p_present
    from attendance
    group by studentid
) a on s.studentid = a.studentid
where a.p_present < 75 ;
```

**Result**

```
+-----------+------+-------+-----------+
| studentid | name | total | p_present |
+-----------+------+-------+-----------+
|         1 | John |     2 |   50.0000 |
|         2 | Matt |     3 |   66.6667 |
+-----------+------+-------+-----------+
```

p_present is percent present. Note that John and Matt had 50% and 66.6% attendance, respectively.

**Explanation**

In order to get total records, we'd do something like this:

```
select studentid, count(*)
from attendance
group by studentid;
```

In order to get total times each student was present, we'd do:

```
select studentid, sum(case attendance when 'p' then 1 else 0 end)
from attendance
group by studentid;
```

% present is going to be the # of times the student was present divided by the total. So, that's what I did in the subquery.

Once the data about the student was available, join that result with student's information and extract the information desired from both tables.